# Clean architecture logging

Tags: logging, clean-architecture

I need to implement logging in Clean Architecture in each layer.

For Domain and application Layer I'll use dependency inversion, creating an interface implemented by WebApi, and injecting it in each class.

For the infrastructure layer, I'll inject in each class the "default" logger instance (NLogger).

It's a correct solution or exists a cleanest,  for example, avoid injecting the logger instance in each class?

Answer (score 3):

Dependency inversion is the correct pattern. All classes should only depend on your own logger interface and only the "main component" (the place where all details are wired together) should know the concrete logger implementation.